# Don't want to show LINK used on IFRAME KML

Tags: kml, google-earth

I know that is possible to display a URL link inside a kml using IFRAME.
But I need that my link used on IFRAME does not display if I do right-click -> Properties in the placemark or in the right list of placemarks.

There's a way to do so?

Thx a lot,

Cya!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

You need to look into using [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata)

It requires you to hand edit the KML file with a text editor.

Step 1 - Within the `<Placemark>` you wish to embed to iframe

```
<ExtendedData>                       
  <Data name="iframe">
    <value><![CDATA[<iframe width="350" height="197" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>]]></value>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

Step 2 - Within the associated `<Style>` assigned to the Placemark

```
<BalloonStyle>
    <text>$[description]$[iframe]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
```

That will work so long as you place everything in the correct place

HOWEVER anyone who really wants to see the source of your iframe - all they have to do is open the KML in a text editor..... so it is kind of a useless process......

Comment: Thanks lifeIsGood, I'll try it.